# how to call variable from config.groovy

Tags: grails, gsp

I am using below code in order to use mail plugin in grails

```
      try {
                CH.config.grails.mail.default.from = "${parent_personal_data.email}"
                mailSender.username = "${parent_personal_data.email}"
                mailSender.password = "${parent_data.password}"
                mailService.sendMail {
                to "${employee_personal_data.email}"
                subject "new task"
                body "you have been added to project and you are given a task"
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
      // catch block code
      }
      // Set the original settings back
      finally {
          CH.config.grails.mail.default.from = defaultFrom
          mailSender.username = oldUsername
          mailSender.password = oldPassword
      }
```

how ever it keep on showing me the error 
NO such property: CH
no such property :mailSender

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what CH is in your code or what version of grails you're using, but the appropriate way to get configuration elements is either via `grailsApplication` or `Holders`.

In a controller or service, you can inject the grailsApplication.

```
class SomeService {
  def grailsApplication

  def someMethod() {
    def from = grailsApplication.config.grails.mail.default.from
    ...
  }
}
```

Or you can use the grails.util.Holders class.

```
class SomeService {
  def grailsApplication

  def someMethod() {
    def from = Holders.config.grails.mail.default.from
    ...
  }
}
```

Read some [docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#config).